# Concurrency in JavaFX - task is not finished

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I have two tasks, one to change screen opacity, the other to perform a complex computation. I wanted the computation to begin only after the screen fading has actually changed so I wrote the following:

```
            Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                stage.getScene().getRoot().setOpacity(0.2);
                stage.show();
                return null;
            }
        };

        Task<Void> task2 = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // Complex computation
                return null;
            }
        };  
        task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent paramT) {
                // this busy waiting line was added in attempt to force the
                // fading before beginning second task
                while (stage.getScene().getRoot().getOpacity() != 0.2) {}   
                stage.show();
                Platform.runLater(task2);
            }
        });
        task2.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent paramT) {
                stage.getScene().getRoot().setOpacity(1);
                stage.show();
            }
        });
        task.run();
```

However, sometimes I see the computation beginning and the screen fading only after it's done. Sometimes it does work. So I think there's a threading issue here. Note: When I'm on debug mode and stop at each task it really works everytime. What can be done to force the screen fade before the second task begins?

EDIT:
As suggested, I changed the code to the following:

```
            Task<Void> task1 = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // Long computation
                return null;
            }
        };  

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(1), stage.getScene().getRoot());
                ft.setFromValue(1.0);
                ft.setToValue(0.1);
                ft.setCycleCount(1);
                //ft.setAutoReverse(true);
                ft.play();

                ft.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        new Thread(task1).run();
                    }
                });

                return null;
            }
        };

        task1.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent paramT) {
                FadeTransition ft1 = new FadeTransition(new Duration(0.1), stage.getScene().getRoot());
                ft1.setFromValue(0.1);
                ft1.setToValue(1.0);
                ft1.setCycleCount(1);
                //ft.setAutoReverse(true);
                ft1.play();
                //stage.show();
            }
        });
        new Thread(task).run();
```

Still I see the same behavior.

Comment: There is so much wrong here it's hard to know where to start. Neither of your `Task`s are executed in background threads  (the first, you just call `run(...)`, which will execute it in the current thread; in the second you go out of your way to execute it on the FX Application Thread by calling `Platform.runLater(...)`). Your first `Task` updates the UI, which would be illegal if you were running in a background thread. `setOpacity(...)` will not create a "fade" as you seem to expect, but will immediately change the opacity. Your `onSucceeded` blocks execution, which will freeze the UI.

Comment: If you want a "fade", use a [`FadeTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/FadeTransition.html). Launch the second task in the fade transition's `onFinished` handler. There will be no need to block here (because the fade will have finished). Launch the task performing the computation in a background thread or pass it to an executor. See the [`Task` Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
new Thread(task).run();
```

with

```
new Thread(task).start();
```

Comment: This wasn't the cause of the error, but still it's good style to invoke start instead of run. Findbugs also found this as an error.